# How to get live data from Maps like Speed, location? Is it possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, maps

So I got a question I don't know if it is possible or not.

I have searched around the web for a while but I could not find anything.

So I have an application that opens Maps app pragmatically when a situation occurs. My question is later when that user is redirected to the Maps app can I get live data feed like speed as it is changing or other values?

Examples or links would be nice if there is such a way to do it

Comment: Use `CLLocationManager`. You can't get anything from the Maps app. And why launch the Maps app from your app? Use an `MKMapView` to stay in your app.

Comment: There are some features that i cant do myself, thats why i need to open Maps app. @maddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the following:

1. Use the MapKit framework and a MapView inside your own app instead of redirecting the user out of your app.
2. If you absolutely have to redirect the user out of your app, then you have to ask for permission from to user to use their location data while your app is in the background. Since they're in Maps and not in your app, you're using their location data in the background. You can read [this article](http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/) on requesting for permission in iOS 8.
3. Get location data by using [`CoreLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/)'s [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager), and implementing the [`CLLocationManagerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate) protocol. There's a delegate method which gives you [`CLLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocation) objects, which in turn hold properties such as `speed`, `course`, etc.

Here's an [EXAMPLE](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_7_Location_Application) for using `CLLocationManager`.

Comment: I see. Yes in that case you would need to use `CLLocationManager` and ask for their permission. I suggest asking for permission right before you redirect them to Maps for the first time.

Comment: Yeah it also said so in the link you provided. I will try to implement this!

Comment: If i would need to send the location(in the background) to a server. What background mode would i need to select? External accessory communication? @armin m